# Iterating through only some members of an array

Tags: java

(Full disclosure: Coming form a Ruby guy who's been away from Java for a while)

```
Entity[] space;

class Planet extends Entity ... 

class Star extends Entity ...
```

The space[] array contains a mixture of nulls, Planets and Stars. I want to do access just the stars in that array (which might be none.)

What's an elegant Java way of doing it, without using `instanceof`

Comment: Why do you want to avoid instanceof ?? For design purpose maybe by using visitor pattern but maybe

Comment: Because I prefer to use some polymorphism pattern

Comment: If you prefer polymorphism, why don't you operate on `Entity` instances, rather than `Star` or `Planet`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Java you generally try to avoid using arrays (because they’re a pain in the butt to work with).

So, first step would be get something from the Collection API to represent your array. A `List` comes to mind!

```
List<Entity> entities = Arrays.asList(space);
```

Now, Java 8 has introduced the Stream API.

```
entities.stream()
    .filter(e -> e != null)
    .filter(e -> e instanceof Star)
    .foreach(e -> doSomethingWithStar((Star) e));
```

If you want to avoid using `instanceof` you need to give your `Entity` class a way to differentiate between stars and other objects. A `boolean isStar()` method might achieve that:

```
entities.stream()
    .filter(e -> e != null)
    .filter(e -> e.isStar())
    .foreach(e -> doSomethingWithStar((Star) e));
```

However, that has still the same problem: the type of the `Stream` is still `Stream<Entity>` even though you now know there are only `Star`s in them.

Other ways of converting an `Entity` into a `Star` or nothing could be to add a `void addStarToList(List<Star> stars)` method that adds an entity to a list if it is a Star but doesn’t add anything if it’s not a star.

```
List<Star> stars = new ArrayList<>();
entities.stream()
    .filter(e -> e != null)
    .foreach(e -> e.addStarToList(stars));
```

Comment: You do not need two filter `e -> e != null && e instanceof Star`

Comment: Of course you don’t. However, separating them makes a lot clearer what is  happening.

Comment: Not to me. All that matters is that it's `instanceof Star`. If clarity is really a priority, prefer method references to lambdas so that that you have a simple, clear name, instead of a lot of embedded code.

Comment: @erickson and as soon as you have a method that you can call you need to check for `null`s again.

Comment: Actually, `null instanceof Star` would evaluate to `false`, so you don't need the explicit null check.

Comment: @Bombe I don't understand. What do you mean?

Comment: @erickson examples two and three in my answer; no way around a `null` check there.

Comment: I see. Yes, if you chose to write that sort of code, you'd want a null check too.

Comment: @erickson hehe, absolutely. I’d rather make sure my input list doesn’t have any `null`s. I’d also make sure it wouldn’t have anything but `Star`s if I only wanted to stars. :)

Comment: Exactly. If you can't treat the objects polymorphically, don't mix them up in the first place.

Comment: Re: not using arrays. Yes I was coming to the same conclusion.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the ideas!

Answer (score 1):

You can invoke `star.doStarSpecificThing()` on all of the `Star` instances like this:

```
Arrays.stream(space)
  .filter(e -> e instanceof Star)
  .map(e -> (Star) e)
  .forEach(Star::doStarSpecificThing);
```

Comment: It does but the output of the `filter` is still an `Entity`. `instanceof` doesn’t cast in Java. :)

Comment: @ErickG.Hagstrom Yes, it's necessary. The result of `Stream<T>.filter()` is `Stream<T>`.